# Juntar 2 SQL com resultados diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql

Funcionam perfeitamente, mas agora preciso junta-las, mas os resultados serão diferentes ou seja não posso unir o resultado, mas sim juntar as SQL e obter o resultado das duas abaixo, mas não sei como fazer.

Veja o que tenho:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.arquivada=1)AS orden, c.nomeCliente  
    FROM tbl_os o  
    INNER JOIN tbl_clientes c 
    ON(o.tecnico = c.id)  
    WHERE o.arquivada=1 
    AND o.tecnico=1 
    AND DAY(o.dataSaida)=x 
    AND MONTH(o.dataSaida) = x

SELECT SUM(a.idTipoAtendimento=1) AS sistema, SUM(a.idTipoAtendimento=2)AS servico, c.nomeCliente 
    FROM tbl_Atendimento a  
    INNER JOIN tbl_clientes c 
    ON(a.tecnico = c.id)  
    WHERE a.arquivada=1 
    AND a.tecnico=1 
    AND DAY(a.dataMarcada)=x 
    AND MONTH(a.dataMarcada) = x
```

Comment: Tem certeza que esses selects funcionam, sem a clausula GROUP BY?

Comment: Como assim juntar sem unir? E não consigo ver "que estão em negrito"

Comment: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/555805-sql-com-2-where-ou-algo-assim/#entry2216981

Comment: Opa, é que sou novo aqui, tinha marcado o negrito mas não saiu.
então essas SELECT funcionam separadas, mas eu preciso do valor COUNT e SUM que estão nelas.

preciso juntar as colunas na mesma SQL, até agora não encontrei nada.

Answer (score 1):

Assim

```
SELECT SUM(Temp.ordem) as ordem, sum(Temp.sistema) as sistema from
(SELECT COUNT(a.arquivada=1)AS orden, 0 as sistema
FROM tbl_os o
INNER JOIN tbl_clientes c ON(o.tecnico = c.id)
WHERE o.arquivada=1 AND o.tecnico=1 AND DAY(o.dataSaida)=x AND MONTH(o.dataSaida) = x
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 as ordem, SUM(a.idTipoAtendimento=1) AS sistema, SUM(a.idTipoAtendimento=2)AS servico, c.nomeCliente FROM tbl_Atendimento a
INNER JOIN tbl_clientes c ON(a.tecnico = c.id)
WHERE a.arquivada=1 AND a.tecnico=1 AND DAY(a.dataMarcada)=x AND MONTH(a.dataMarcada) = x)
as Temp
```

o que fazemos antes de unir as duas queries é garantir que elas possuem as mesmas colunas, por isso SELECT ... 0 as ordem...

Em seguida uso o Sum(Temp.ordem) para que os dois resultados fiquem na mesma linha.